# How do I patrol in Starcraft 2 using QWERT key-layout?

Tags: starcraft-2

I played some years ago and used to use a patrol- and hold-position command with my units, but I cannot find it anymore in the game.

Did they abandon that function? and if, why and is there an alternative?

Is there an icon to click on? I use the QWERT keys, so I don't have "P" as it says in all tutorials

Comment: I edited the title, the problem was, that I used the QWERT Layout and I had enabled the "ENABLE Simple Command Card" in Game Options

Comment: @Arperum that's inappropriately snide, especially since it's incorrect *(you seem to have forgotten that there's a second layout, grid, which is actually [the more efficient of the two](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5886)...)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft My excuses for being snarky. Excuses to rubo77 too. I never played the game and assumed bad will (I'm having not exactly my best day). I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable the option "ENABLE Simple Command Card" in Game Options.

Then you will see that **Hold is "E" and Patrol is "R"** if you have the QWERT-Keyboardlayout.

An unconvenient alternative to patrolling would be setting a lot of waypoints with Shift-"T"-leftclick

Answer (score 0):

Check your controls, but by default patrol should respond to pressing 'P'

Also, they haven't abandoned it for sure. In fact, patrolling is one of the easier (and more efficient) ways to split marines.

Some more info here: http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Hotkeys#Patrol

Comment: yes I came from this video that patroling should be the solution: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uem13jUXnWM